# html behaving differently after adding django template tags

Tags: html, django, css, django-templates

My nav pills appears in a single row. But once I add django template tags to it, the pills stacks on top of each another.

How do I fix it so that the pills appear all in one row?

Without django tags

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills">
  <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
  <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Profile</a></li>
  <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Messages</a></li>
</ul>
```

With django tags

```
{% for menu in menus %}
<ul class="nav nav-pills">
    {% if menu.mealtype == 'Breakfast' %}
        <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    {% endif %}
    {% if menu.mealtype == 'Lunch' %}
        <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Profile</a></li>
    {% endif %}
</ul>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that your for loop `{% for menu in menus %}` repeats the `<ul>` tag as well. You are making a separate list per entry.

Try moving your `for` loop inside the `<ul>` tags.

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills">
{% for menu in menus %}
    {% if menu.mealtype == 'Breakfast' %}
        <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    {% endif %}
    {% if menu.mealtype == 'Lunch' %}
        <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Profile</a></li>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. Works perfectly